# Fetch multiple entities with no relation between them

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, fetch, nsfetchrequest

I have a core data model with multiple entities, each entity corresponds to a view controller were the user inserts information for each entity, for example:

Tire(first Entity) - Type(first atribute), cost(second atribute).
Glass(second Entity) - Color(first atribute), size(second atribute), cost(third atribute).

For each entity i have a MVC with textfields were the user inserts information for each entity, so if you press tire button, you insert a type of tire, cost.. and so on for the other entities.

Everything goes well when i pull just one entity, i insert the information in the textfields then press save, and it appears on my tableview nicely!. But, as you already know, i want the rest of the entities inserted in my tableview and in different sections.

I´ve tried "messing" with the "cellForRowAtIndexPath", also in my "fetchedResultsController" method´s with "if´s" and "swich´s" but with no success. What am i missing here?!?!?!

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a single entity to have your `NSFetchedResultsController` work properly and take advantage of its advanced memory and performance features.

So modify your data model and make one new entity, `Item` that is an **abstract parent entity** of the other entities. (You can assign parent entities in the model editor.) Make sure that the attributes that are shared by all the items (e.g. a name) belong to the parent. These should be the attributes that you want to display in your table view.

Now you could add an `NSString` or `NSNumber` attribute `type` unique for each sub-entity and easily sort by this key in your `NSFetchedResultsController`.

From Apple's [Core Data Programming guide][1] :

> If you define an entity inheritance hierarchy (see “Entity Inheritance”), when you specify a super-entity as the entity for a fetch request, the request returns all matching instances of the super-entity and of sub-entities. In some applications, you might specify a super-entity as being abstract (see “Abstract Entities”). To fetch matching instances of all concrete sub-entities of the abstract entity, you set the entity for fetch specification to be the abstract entity. In the case of the domain described in “Abstract Entities,” if you specify a fetch request with the Graphic entity, the fetch returns matching instances of Circle, TextArea, and Line.

So you fetch all `Items`, sort by `type`, and for each cell you determine the type and fill your text labels with the appropriate properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mundi!. Let me see if i understood, and please correct me if i´m wrong, you´re saying that i should have only one entity that has all the atributes that i wanted before in each entity? but what if (when displaying the cells in tableview) i want to distinguish the product "tire" from the "glass"? how can i manage this in the cell.textlabel.text and cell.detailtextabel.text inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath?. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help mundi, i´m going to implement that.